# Make one Texture out of two TextureRegions

Tags: java, libgdx

I write a little Game for myself and now I have the problem that I need to put two `TextureRegions` together to one Texture. I have already tried it with `Pixmaps`, but it does not work for me. Is there any way to solve that problem

Comment: what is the dimension of your two TextureRegion, Is both are of same dimension and how you want to put these two TextureRegion horizontally or vertically or some orientation ?

Comment: Show the code you used so we can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: they both are of same dimension and i want to put them horizontally together. @Tenfour: my problem is that i have no idea how to manage that and so there is no code to show

Comment: Can't you just draw them next to each other aligned?

Comment: No, that woult create performance issues. i need to put many small textureRegions together to a big one

Answer (score 0):

How did you try with `Pixmap`? This works perfectly:

```
    Pixmap combinedPixmap = new Pixmap(totalWidth, totalHeight, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
    Pixmap pixmap1, pixmap2;
    Texture texture1 = Your texture region.getTexture() /* Your texture region 1 */;
    Texture texture2 = Your texture region.getTexture() /* Your texture region 2 */;
    TextureData data1 = texture1.getTextureData();
    TextureData data2 = texture2.getTextureData();
    if(!data1.isPrepared()) data1.prepare();
    if(!data2.isPrepared()) data2.prepare();
    pixmap1 = data1.consumePixmap();
    pixmap2 = data2.consumePixmap();
    combinedPixmap.drawPixmap(pixmap1, 0, 0);
    combinedPixmap.drawPixmap(pixmap2, 100, 0);
    Texture finalTexture = new Texture(combinedPixmap);
```

If for some reason it doesn't, you can use `Framebuffers`.

```
    FrameBuffer fbo = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, totalWidth, totalHeight, false);
    fbo.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    spriteBatch.draw(region1, 0, 0);
    spriteBatch.draw(region2, 100, 0);
    spriteBatch.flush();
    fbo.end();
    TextureRegion combinedRegion = new TextureRegion(fbo.getColorBufferTexture());
    combinedRegion.flip(false, true);
    Texture combined = combinedRegion.getTexture();
```

More info on framebuffers:

- https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/FrameBufferObjects
- https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/glutils/FrameBuffer.html

Comment: i am using a texture atlas and so this line:                                           Texture texture1 = Your texture region.getTexture() ; will return the whole texture, not only the textureregion. And i was hoping that their would be a better solution than just copying each pixel that i want for my image from the texture to the pixmap